# In how many ways can 11 people be seated in a row of 16 seats so that there are not two consecutive empty seats.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have this question, in how many ways can $11$ people be seated in a row of $16$ seats so that there are not two consecutive empty seats?

I know that there are at least 11! ways on how to arrange people, however I do find the confusion by removing the 5 seats that are empty.

Comment: What does "there are at least one person seated in one seat" mean?

Comment: Just one person on one seat, going to edit the question!

Comment: I think it goes without saying that each person takes exactly one seat.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: To your question:  to count the possible patterns, suppose we had the five empty seats in a row, with gaps between them.  There are $6$ gaps defined by the empty seats, $4$ of which can not bet $0$.  This lets you change the problem into a standard [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.) question.

Comment: Thank you @lulu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$11! \times C(12,5)$.

First decide on the order left-to-right of the 11 folks.

Imagine a gap between people, including both ends, for a total of 12 gaps.

Pick 5 of the 12 gaps to "put down" the 5 empty seats.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to "stars and bars." The stars here are people and the bars will be empty seats. There are 11! orderings of the people, *once the occupied seats are chosen*. So first pick such an ordering of people. Next, there are 11+1=12 possible locations for empty seats between the people. Since you need 5 empty seats, there are $\binom{12}{5}$ ways to pick the empty seats. Thus you get $11!\binom{12}{5}$ possible ways.